# How to find the next element in a generic List?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, generics

This is my Generic List:

public class TagType
            {
                public string FieldTag;
                public int Position;
            }

```
List<TagType<dynamic>> TagList = new List<TagType<dynamic>>();

TagList.Add(new TagType<dynamic>() { FieldTag = "ID", Position = posIdStr });
TagList.Add(new TagType<dynamic>() { FieldTag = "PT", Position = posPtStr });
TagList.Add(new TagType<dynamic>() { FieldTag = "ID", Position = posIdStr });
TagList.Add(new TagType<dynamic>() { FieldTag = "EC", Position = posECStr });
```

I am trying to get Position value for the FieldTag that comes after (for eg: PT).
How do I do this?

Comment: What if the one you're looking for is not in there? What if it's the last item? What if there are multiple? What have you tried?

Comment: I wonder why no one suggested using a `LinkedList<TagType<dynamic>>` instead of `List<TagType<dynamic>>`, then you would have on each entry a `.Next` and `.Previous` properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You find the index of `PT` and add 1? (but remember to check that the index + 1 < the length of the List)

```
// Find the index of PT
int ix = TagList.FindIndex(x => x.FieldTag == "PT");

// index found
if (ix != -1)
{
    // Check that index + 1 < the length of the List
    if (ix + 1 < TagList.Count)
    {
        var position = TagList[ix + 1]; // Add 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately each time you do a search you will have to iterate over the list, find the field tag you are looking for, then go to the next element and get the position value. e..: An **O(n)** for lookup solution:

```
    private static object SearchPosition(List<TagType<object>> tagList, string fieldTag)
    {
        var i = tagList.FindIndex(x => x.FieldTag == "PT");

        if (i >= 0 && i < tagList.Count)
        {
            return tagList[i + 1].Position;
        }
    }
```

And test:

```
    [Test]
    public void FieldTagTest()
    {
        var res = SearchPosition(_tagList, "PT");

        res.ToString().Should().Be("ID2");
    }
```

If your list does not change often, you should build a `Dictionary<string,int>` with the `FieldTag` as `Key`and the list index position as `value`. Ofcourse each time you modify the list you would need to build this index again.

An **O(1)** solution is:

```
    private static object SearchPositionUsingIndex(List<TagType<object>> tagList, string fieldTag)
    {
        // You would save this index, and build it only once, 
        // or rebuild it whenver something changes.
        // you could implement custom index modifications.
        var index = BuildIndex(tagList);

        int i;
        if (!index.TryGetValue(fieldTag, out i)) return null;
        if (i + 1 >= tagList.Count) return null;
        return tagList[i + 1].Position;
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, int> BuildIndex(List<TagType<object>> tagList)
    {
        var index = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < tagList.Count; i++)
        {
            var tag = tagList[i];
            if (!index.ContainsKey(tag.FieldTag)) index.Add(tag.FieldTag, i);
        }
        return index;
    }
```

And test:

```
    [Test]
    public void FieldTagTestUsingIndex()
    {
        var res = SearchPositionUsingIndex(_tagList, "PT");

        res.ToString().Should().Be("ID2");
    }
```

Or you could use a 1 line LINQ method, which is also **O(n)**:

```
    [Test]
    public void FieldTagTestLinq()
    {
        var res = SearchUsingLinq();

        res.ToString().Should().Be("ID2");
    }

    private object SearchUsingLinq()
    {
        var p = _tagList.SkipWhile(x => x.FieldTag != "PT").Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
        return p != null ? p.Position : null;
    }
```

**TestSetup**

```
public class SO29047477
{
    private List<TagType<object>> _tagList;

    [SetUp]
    public void TestSetup()
    {
        _tagList = new List<TagType<dynamic>>();

        _tagList.Add(new TagType<dynamic>() { FieldTag = "ID", Position = "ID1"});
        _tagList.Add(new TagType<dynamic>() { FieldTag = "PT", Position = "PT1" });
        _tagList.Add(new TagType<dynamic>() { FieldTag = "ID", Position = "ID2" });
        _tagList.Add(new TagType<dynamic>() { FieldTag = "EC", Position = "EC1" });

    }
}
```

Comment: Premature optimization (maybe `O(n)` isn't a problem as `n` stays small, and given one lookup your solution is still `O(n)` as you'll have to build the dictionary), worse maintainability (because more code and having to keep list and dictionary in sync), and this assumes each FieldTag occurs only once or only the first should be found.

Comment: I agree yes, but if he gave a small snippet of code, and there a 1000s of tag types, being searched for multiple of times then its worth putting that answer out there. Yes for 1 lookup it makes no sense. But I have seen small data sets, grow over time to large data sets ;-)

Comment: Indeed, premature optimization is the root of all evil. But if his TagList is coming from an external source, which is likely to grow, sooner or later he will have a problem if he needs to do multiple searches.

Comment: Yeah but like in most cases on SO, the question is then too broad and the proper answer would be "Your approach is wrong, start over". I don't blame you, just had to point those things out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get next element's `Position` after each item with `FieldTag` PT, then you can solve it in one or two lines with LINQ:

```
var resultTag = TagList.SkipWhile(x => x.FieldTag != "PT").Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
var resultPosition = resultTag == null ?  0 : resultTag.Position;
```

***Additional:***
If you want to cast it to `int` then just cast it explicitly.

```
var resultTag = TagList.SkipWhile(x => x.FieldTag != "PT").Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
int resultPosition = resultTag == null ?  0 : (int)resultTag.Position;
```

Comment: This would have to be TagsList.Where().SKip. First() would return the tag list straight away

Comment: Also your `FirstOrDefautlt.Position` will throw NullReference exception, better of usign First ;-) Or getting it and checking for null before calling `.Position`

Comment: Also you skip while returns the first string ;-) as it comes across FieldTag of ID, and it sees ok, its not PT, So you need to use where

Comment: `_tagList.SkipWhile(x => x.FieldTag != "PT").Skip(1).First().Position;`

Comment: @MichalCiechan Thanks. ;) But, `SkipWhile` is OK, I just need to change `==` to `!=`

Comment: @MichalCiechan Yes, you have passed ahead me in 17 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Position? GetNextPosition(string FieldTagVal)
{
    bool returnNext = false;
    foreach(TagType t in TagList) 
    {
       if (returnNext) return t.Position;
       if (t.FieldTag == FieldTagVal) returnNext = true;
    }
    return null;
}
```